# Virus run by postgres user?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I've found a program named `wipefs` run by the `postgres` user. The server is a *Ubuntu 12.04*.

When I did `ps ax|grep wipefs` I've got:

`10209 ?        Sl     1:04 /var/tmp/.ICE-unix/-l/.db/wipefs --library-path /var/tmp/.ICE-unix/-l/.db /var/tmp/.ICE-unix/-l/.db/x`

Then I did this:

`ls -lah /var/tmp/.ICE-unix/-l/.db/
total 14M
drwxr-xr-x 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jun 11 19:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 postgres postgres 4.0K Jul 17 21:00 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 1.8M Nov 20  2017 libc.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 2.3M Nov 20  2017 libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  15K Nov 20  2017 libdl.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  31K Nov 20  2017 libffi.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  88K Nov 20  2017 libgcc_s.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 898K Nov 20  2017 libgcrypt.so.20
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 511K Nov 20  2017 libgmp.so.10
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 1.2M Nov 20  2017 libgnutls.so.30
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  79K Nov 20  2017 libgpg-error.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 203K Nov 20  2017 libhogweed.so.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 232K Nov 20  2017 libhwloc.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 203K Nov 20  2017 libidn.so.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  39K Nov 20  2017 libltdl.so.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 1.1M Nov 20  2017 libm.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  95K Nov 20  2017 libmicrohttpd.so.10
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 215K Nov 20  2017 libnettle.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  43K Nov 20  2017 libnuma.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 399K Nov 20  2017 libp11-kit.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 136K Nov 20  2017 libpthread.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres   77 Jun 11 19:21 libq.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  31K Nov 20  2017 librt.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  280 May 15 19:52 libs.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 419K Nov 20  2017 libssl.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 1.5M Nov 20  2017 libstdc++.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres  75K Nov 20  2017 libtasn1.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 103K Nov 20  2017 libz.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 159K Nov 20  2017 wipefs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 2.1M Jun  3 15:04 x`

In other systems running PostgreSql the directory `/tmp/.ICE-unix` is empty.

Is this a virus?.

Answer (score 3):

It **definitely looks like a piece of malware**; but since it does not seem to attach itself to other programs, but instead "lives" as an independent entity, it is not technically a *virus* but possibly a *worm*.

[See this question for recommended next steps.](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/442837)

`/tmp/.ICE-unix` would be the normal directory for UNIX sockets used for communicating with a X11 GUI session manager. `/var/tmp/.ICE-unix` has nothing to do with it, but is clearly using similar naming to make the malware's directories appear uninteresting to casual notice.

The fact that it's running as the `postgres` user suggests it might have got in through the Postgres database engine, and inherited the user identity of Postgres processes as a result.

*If* the library names are genuine, this malware sure seems to carry a lot of encryption implementations with it: `libssl` and `libcrypto` are OpenSSL, then there is `libgnutls`, the pair of `libhogweed` and `libnettle`, and also `libgcrypt`. It also has `libmicrohttpd`, which suggests it could be running some sort of HTTP-based network service, possibly an encrypted one.

If it consumes a lot of CPU power but does not seem to be doing much with any files, my first guess would be a coin miner. But this is just a guess; it might be something worse.

By running `lsof -p 10209` as root, you might be able to see which files this process is touching and what network connections it has. If some files are marked as `(deleted)`, you might be able to still access them via `/proc/10209/fd/` as long as the files are still held open by the process.

If you want to investigate further, grab a copy of the malware's files and scan them with some virus scanner.

Anyway, if you have other similar systems, you should be seriously thinking about restricting access to them from Internet to the minimum required, and updating them. Ubuntu 12.04's support ended in April 2017, more than a year ago.

For this particular system: you should treat it as contaminated and no longer secure. It might be that this is the only piece of malware on the system, but it's very difficult to really confirm that: wiping the system and restoring from backups is usually much quicker and easier.